# How to pass variable from Module to Controller in Yii2?

Tags: api, rest, yii2

I am building restful stateless API using Yii2... So far so good. Now I failed at rookie problem.

I have decided to make API application (preferred by Yii) and make API as a module. So my structure is:

```
- modules
-- v1
--- components
--- controllers
--- models
```

Inside v1 folder of course there is Module.php. In here I do authentication like:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            'auth' => function($username, $password) {
            ... get user's data from DB ...
            [HERE]
            }
    ];
```

and at point `[HERE]` I sotre user's ID in public variable.

So far so good...

So when I for example call `v1/abc/index` abc controller loads in inside that controller I would like to access user's ID stored at point `[HERE]`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access module from controller, you should simply use `$this->module`.

And from a view : `$this->context->module`.

No need to use `getModule()` here.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#$module-detail

PS: to access module outside its controllers/views you could use :

```
Yii::app()->getModule('module');
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
$v1Module = Yii::app()->getModule('v1');
```

And then simply

```
echo $v1Module->yourPublicVariable;
```

Comment: Wow... Yii2 keeps impressing me ... Did not even thought of this simple solution! Thanks a lot!